# pass-protected pages and posts not protected after enter them 1 time

Tags: cache, session

i use wordpress 3.9.2 and i read a lot of article and Q about clear cookies but some of them is too old ( for wp 3.4 and wp-pass with different code) or not solve my problem

i have some password protected pages and posts

they work well and wants password for see them , but after i enter password and open a protected post or pages

they will not act like a protected page anymore !! they are just like normal posts !!

it` too bad for me cause maybe my customers that have these pass open these pages in coffee net or somewhere like that !!

i read some post about clear cookie after a few min but they are not obvious and they are for wp 3.4 ( wp-pass.php)

i found this on wp-login:
$expire = apply_filters( 'post_password_expires', time() + 10 * DAY_IN_SECONDS );

but no clue it`s what i need or not and how can i define a time for example 5 minutes !

i have no user login in my site and the password protected is nice for me .

it will be Great if there is a way to clear cookie or cache after close the window of browsers or a few minutes after entering pages or posts ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it seems that the `post_password_expires` filter is what you are looking for. According to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_password_expires/) you just need to add

```
function wpse166590_cockie_timeout($timeout) {
   return time() + 5 * 60; // 5 minute in seconds
}

add_filter('post_password_expires','wpse166590_cockie_timeout');
```

Comment: thanks so much 

i put your code in my function.php but now when i enter password on my page it`s act like my pass is wrong and password box load again 

i remove your code and the password pages works well again !!

what wrong ??

Comment: sorry, me bad, updating the answer